# How does regularization shrink the parameters?

Tags: machine-learning

This is actually probably a simple question but I'm a little confused. Here is the squared error cost function

Comment: You shrink the parameter theta because you minimize `J(theta)` and large theta are pushing against the goal of minimizing `J`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically you are trying to minimize `J`, which is of the form

```
J(theta) = f(theta) + lambda*||theta||^2
```

Now, this first term measures how big is an empirical error (fitting to the data), and the second one measures how big is your parameters vector. You are minimizing the sum of two values, so in order to acheive small values you have to more or less minimize both of them. Of course, it might still be the case, that for some very big theta, f(theta) is so small, the minimum is obtained there. But this is where the meaning of lambda appears - by setting high lambda you make growth of theta more and more expensive, so the optimization procedure has to reduce size of theta used in order to achieve minimum of the function.

Comment: Thank you for this. I think I am getting it, maybe, Can you tell me if my understanding here is correct. https://slimgur.com/image/WP9